# Where can I see the Achievements?

Tags: achievements, assassins-creed-3

In Assassins Creed III, I sometimes see "Brawler" or hunting achievements pop up, like

> Kill a captain (4/10)

Where can I view the open achievements I still have to do? I couldn't find it anywhere in the menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's in the Logbook - this will be not on the regular menu interface but on the same screen as the map.  Just scroll down. (On PS3 this is accessed with Select, I can't speak for other platforms)